# How can I disable a button on my page if I know only the name of that element?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="setThemeColor(this.name)">Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="setThemeColor(this.name)">Black</button>
```

and this script:

```
if (localStorage.buttonColor) {
   var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".theme");
   for (var button in themeButtons) {
      themeButtons[buttons].removeAttribute("disabled");
   }
   // I need here to disable the button with the name that matches localstorage name
}
```

I already have in place a way to remove the disabled from all the buttons. But how can I after that disable the button which has the same name as the localStorage.buttonColor without using jQuery?

Also could I do all this in the `for (var button in themeButtons)` loop? If I could do that it might be even more clean of a solution.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there's only one button:

```
document.querySelector('button[name="' + localStorage.buttonColor + '"]').disabled = true;
```

Or:

```
var el = document.getElementsByName(localStorage.buttonColor);
if (el) {
    el[0].disabled = true;
}
```

If there are multiple elements:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="' + localStorage.buttonColor + '"]');
for (var i = 0, len = all.length; i<len; i++){
    all[i].disabled = true;
}
```

If there are multiple buttons, and you need to enable the ones that don't share the name of the `localStorage.buttonColor`:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    buttonsQSA = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// iterate over whichever collection you prefer to use
for (var i = 0, len = buttonsQSA.length; i<len; i++){
    buttonsQSA[i].disabled = buttonsQSA[i].name == localStorage.buttonColor;
}
```

Comment: Hello David. Can you explain the difference between your two answers and let me know if one might be better than the other. There are multiple buttons. The one (there will be only one) that has a name that matches local storage needs to be disabled. The others need "disabled" removed. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` requires a modern/up-to-date browser (but you're already using `.querySelectorAll()` which has the exact same requirement), and this will only ever retrieve one element (the first match it finds). The latter approach will retrieve all elements of that name (regardless of the element-type), which is less-specific, but has better, by far, cross-browser compatibility.